# Why there exists a group homomorphism $f_t$ such that $f = pf_t$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $p: X^{'} \rightarrow X$ and $f: Y \rightarrow X$ be two group homomorphism such that $f(Y) \subset p(X^{'})$. Why does there exists a homomorphism $f_t:Y \rightarrow X^{'}$ such that $f = pf_t$?

Does it involve only group homomorphisms or is there a 'certain' universal property involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a homomorphism $f_t$ does **not** generally exist.

For a counterexample, let $p : X' = \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2 = X$ be the unique nontrivial surjective homomorphism from the group of integers to the cyclic group of order $2$, and let $f : Y = \mathbb Z/2 \to \mathbb Z / 2 = X$ be the identity homomorphism. The only homomorphism $f_t : \mathbb Z / 2 \to \mathbb Z$ is the trivial homomorphism, which violates the equation $f = p f_t$.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a property: take $X'=\mathbb{Z}$ and $Y=X=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then, for $p:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ the projection morphism and $f=\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$, even if you have your condition (both images are whole $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$), you can't find any morphism $f_t$ satisfying what you want (every morphism $\varphi$ from $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is $0$: $0=\varphi(0)=\varphi(2a)=2\varphi(a)$).